Space evenly between categories
I am making the homepage for an app and every circle it's not in line ( horizontally and vertically) here it's a photo to understand better what I am telling : 
What I should change to the code to make them equal and the text to not be affected, here it's some of the codelines , it will continue with another row same stuff but I am interested if I should wrap each row in something or add alignment or axis alignment or what to do
class CategoriesScroller extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesScroller();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double categoryHeight =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.30 - 50;
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 20),
            child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          List<String> location = await getLocation();
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => TransportScreen(
                                "Xoxoxoox",
                                location,
                                
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(180.0))),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text(
                                  'xoxo',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          List<String> location = await getLocation();
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => TransportScreen(
                                  "xoxoxox",
                                  location,
                                  'assets/images/backgroundcategory.png'),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(180.0))),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text('xoxo',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          List<String> location = await getLocation();
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => TransportScreen(
                                    "Xoxoxoxooxoxo",
                                    location,
                                    "assets/images/backgroundcategory.png")),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(180.0))),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text('xoxoxoxooxoxoxo',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          List<String> location = await getLocation();
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => TransportScreen(
                                    "Xoxoxoxo",
                                    location,
                                    "/Users/lilianasanda/Desktop/assets/images/backgroundcategory.png")),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              width: 80,
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                           
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                      Radius.circular(180.0))),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Text('xoxo',
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),


You can use SliverGrid for this problem. You can create rows and columns more neatly with SliverGrid.
The sample code I made is as follows:
class CategoriesScroller extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesScroller({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Map<String, String>> categories = [
      {'label': 'xoxo'},
      {'label': 'oxoxoxoxoxo'},
      {'label': 'xoxoxoxo'},
      {'label': 'oxox'},
      {'label': 'oxoxoxoxoxooxoxoxoxoxo'},
      {'label': 'xoxoxoxoxo'},
      {'label': 'xoxoxoxoxooxoxox'},
      {'label': 'xoxoxoxoxooxoxoxoo'},
      {'label': 'oxoxox'},
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 150.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                childAspectRatio: 0.8,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 80,
                        width: 80,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 228, 228),
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(180.0)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          categories[index]['label']!,
                          style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                },
                childCount: categories.length,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

This is what it looks like:


It's messing a bit my code, because my code has more than what I post, so there is no constraint I can add to make the space equal between them?

This is the solution that comes to my mind. You can make more frequent and wider placements by changing the values of the parameters in the gridDelegate.
